# Gradient, Laplace operator

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis, cylindrical-coordinates

Could someone help me with the following question?
The scalar field f and the vector field F in cylindricalcoordinates are given by $\displaystyle f=\frac{cos(\theta)}{r}$ respective $\displaystyle\vec{F} = \frac{cos \theta}{r} \hat{\theta}$

Compute $\nabla f$, $\nabla^{2}f$, $\nabla \cdot F$, $\nabla \times F$

I got $\displaystyle \nabla f=-\frac{cos\theta}{r^2}\hat r-\frac{sin\theta}{r}\hat \theta$

But it is wrong :(( I have exam in two days I should know those calculations :((

**EDIT:** I think i forgot the scale factors? If yes, then i think i need help with $\nabla \cdot F$, $\nabla \times F$

Comment: Check out: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates

Comment: I got now: $ \nabla f=-\frac{cos\theta}{r^2}\hat r-\frac{sin\theta}{r^2}\hat \theta$. I missed the scale factor, that is why i got wrong answer. But I could not solve the Laplace operator. Could you help me?

Comment: Yes, now your result seems appropriate. The laplace operator  is also listed on the wikipage I sent you. If you are stuck with some point please show your working and where you got stuck.